# Gauss Markov Theorem for linear combinations

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, gauss-markov-theorem

I know that the Gauss Markov theorem implies that under some conditions, OLS estimates have the smallest variance of all unbiased linear estimators.
In particular if I have a model like $ y = \alpha + \beta_1.x_1 + \beta_2.x_2$ then I know that my OLS estimate $\hat{\beta}_1$ has smallest variance and my estimate $\hat{\beta}_2$ has also smallest variance.
But is it true that my estimate of $\hat{\beta}_2 - \hat{\beta}_1$ has the smallest variance?

Comment: Use your algebra to observe $y = \alpha + (\beta_2-\beta_1)(x_2-x_1)/2+(\beta_2+\beta_1)(x_2+x_1)/2=\alpha+\alpha_1(x_2-x_1)/2+\alpha_2(x_2+x_1)/2$ and consider how your OLS estimates of the $\beta_i$ and $\alpha_i$ might be related.

Comment: Yes, [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#Remarks_on_the_proof) gives a complete account on this.

Comment: @Zhanxiong  this doesn't talk my question because in my case, $var(\beta_2 - \beta_1) = var(\beta_2) + var(\beta_1) - 2cov(\beta_2, \beta_1)$ and since the $cov$ is negative here, following the proofs, $cov(\beta_2, \beta_1)$ for OLS is the smallest, and so substracting that from the whole variance difference, leaves ambiguous effects no?

Comment: @jbowman thank you so much! But not really, since if you look at my comment just above this one, I have a negative sign in front of the covariance so this wouldn't really work, in fact leaves me with an ambiguous result.

Comment: @Lola1993 To be more specific, I presume you are asking $\hat{\beta}_2 - \hat{\beta}_1$ has the minimal variance among all unbiased linear estimator of the parameter $\beta_2 - \beta_1$.  Is that what you meant (after all, GM theorem is restricting on the ULE family)?

Comment: @Zhanxiong yes exactly!!!

Comment: Then the link provides a good proof.  I don't understand your comment above.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Here is what I don't get:
I need to show that for any other unbiased linear estimators, $\tilde{\beta_1}, \tilde{\beta_2}$, then $var(\tilde{\beta_1} - \tilde{\beta_2}) - var(\hat{\beta_1} - hat{\beta_2}) = M$ where M is a PSD matrix. But, $$var(\tilde{\beta_1} - \tilde{\beta_2}) = var(\tilde{beta_1}) + \var(\beta_2}) - 2cov(\beta_1},\beta_2)$$.
It follows from your link that $var(\tilde{beta_1}) - var(\hat{beta_1})$ gives a PSD matrix and that $var(\tilde{beta_2}) - var(\hat{beta_2})$ gives a PSD matrix. But then, the same goes for the $cov$, but i have to take it negatively.

Comment: Subtraction is the same as addition, just with a negative number.   The point is that you have a linear combination of the parameters estimated, and that's what the proof covers - much more general than just subtracting one parameter from the other.

Comment: @Lola1993 I provided a more direct proof, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}$

Suppose that $a'y$ is an unbiased linear estimator of $\beta_2 - \beta_1 =: c'\beta$ where $c = (0, -1, 1)'$ and $\beta = (\alpha, \beta_1, \beta_2)'$. Note that, the following proof clearly generalizes to all linear functionals of $\beta$ and any design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with $\operatorname{rank}(X) = p$.

By $E[a'y] = c'\beta$, it follows that $a'X\beta = c'\beta$, where $X$ is the design matrix.  Because this holds for all $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, this requires $c = X'a$.  It then follows that
\begin{align}
 & \Var(a'y) - \Var(c'\hat{\beta}) \\
=& \sigma^2(a'a - c'(X'X)^{-1}c) \\
=& \sigma^2(a'a - a'X(X'X)^{-1}X'a) \\
=& \sigma^2a'(I - H)a \\
=& \sigma^2 ((I - H)a)'((I - H)a) \geq 0.
\end{align}

In the above derivation, $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$ is the hat matrix, which is idempotent and symmetric.  Consequently, $I - H$ is idempotent, which entails the desired result.